# How to find all of an SQLAlchemy model's hybrid attributes?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to find a way to get a list of all of an SQLAlchemy models hybrid properties.

For relationships on a Person instance I can do something like:

```
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect
inspect(person.__class__).relationships
```

Is there something like:

```
 inspect(person.__class__).hybrid_properties
```

Comment: Can you help to select your answer below accepted cause it greatly works!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a solution I came up with:

```
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect as sa_inspect
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

for item in sa_inspect(A_MODEL_INSTANCE.__class__).all_orm_descriptors:
    if type(item) == hybrid_property:
        print item.__name__
```

Comment: Great great found! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for sharing, it seems the syntax has changed: `[item for item in sa_inspect(Travel).all_orm_descriptors if isinstance(item, hybrid_property)]` does the trick. The `sa_inspect` expects a class definition directly (`__class__` raises `sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available for object of type <class 'type'>`)